# Automatic padding in Bootstrap5

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

I'm having trouble figuring out why am I getting a constant padding at the bottom of my container in Bootstrap5. I tried using `align-items-center` in the `row` to center the content, but that didn't work.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/4b6937b5e3.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
   
    <div class="container-fluid bg-dark text-light">
        <section class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
                <p>lorem</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
                <p>lorem</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
                <p>lorem</p>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go...

It's because there's a `margin-bottom` set to the `<p>` tag.

Add the following to your CSS:

```
p {
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}
```

See the snippet below.

```css
p {
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/4b6937b5e3.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container-fluid bg-dark text-light">
    <section class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
        <p>lorem</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
        <p>lorem</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
        <p>lorem</p>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried using `py-0` on the container and `no-gutter` on the row since that was suggested, but that didn't work.

Comment: You're welcome. :) The problem was with the `<p>` tag not with the `row`/`container`. That's why you were not able to solve the problem this way.